# Como Completar las Opciones de un Select con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy tratando de dar opciones a mi select al dar click en un boton, pero no me muestra. mi index es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!--<script src="ss/code/highcharts.js"></script>-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" ></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function completa(){

        $.ajax({
            data: "",
            url:"opciones.php",
            type:"POST",
            success: function(vista){
                $("#complet_opt").html(vista);
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
  <body>
<button type='button' class="btn btn-info" onclick="completa();"> Modificar</button>
    </br></br></br>
<label style="color: #ff0000" >WEEK:</label>

<select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" >
<option value="">Seleccione:</option>
<div id="complet_opt" >
</div>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

y de donde se traeran valores sera de opciones.php:

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("mi_base",$con);
 $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(week) as y FROM datos "); 
  while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
  echo "<option value='".$data['y']."' $selected>".$data['y']."</option>"; 
  }
?>
```

pero no se puede mostrar, que es lo que le falta?

Comment: Mira en las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador (F12), cuando haces click al botón ¿ves que la llamada se ejecuta en el tab de red?, ¿ves algún error de js en la consola?

Comment: no naa, ningun error

Comment: Tu código tiene muchos problemas. El 1º es que, cuando intento probarlo sale este error: *`"Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3"`* Luego, tienes un `select` y dentro de él un `div` y es en el `div` donde pretendes poner las opciones. Deberías sacar ese `div` de ahí, y darle el `id="complet_opt "` al `select`, no al `div`. Y si vamos al servidor. Estas usando una extensión obsoleta para la base de datos, si tienes PHP 7 ese código no funcionará. Tampoco controlas nada sobre consultas vacías. Asumes que siempre devolverá algo...

Comment: ... siguiendo con el código PHP, usas ahí una variable `$selected` que no sé de donde la sacas ni para qué sirve. ¿Es que quieres que todos aparezcan como `selected`? Y esa mezcal de PHP/HTML no soy siquiera capaz de analizarla: `echo "<option value='".$data['y']."' $selected>".$data['y']."</option>";`  eso habría que llevarlo a un laboratorio para saber si tiene error o no. No se sabe ahí cuando estás con `"` o cuando estás con `'` . Es muy fácil concatenar el código de una forma más limpia y más clara.

Comment: lo del bootstrap creo que es secundario, porque es para el diseño, con respecto a la consulta que mencionas realizo otras consultas en otros programas usando ajax y ejecuta normalmente, y con respecto a sacar el div, es alli donde era el problema...gracias A. Cedano

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es meter las opciones directamente en el select, no dentro de un `<div/>` *en* el select (lo cual no es válido):

```
<select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" >
    <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function completa(){

    $.ajax({
        data: "",
        url:"opciones.php",
        type:"POST",
        success: function(vista){
            $(".form-control").html(vista);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Te copio el código de ejemplo:

```js
const opciones = '<option>Opcion 1</option><option>Opcion 2</option><option>Opcion 3</option>';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
      $('.select-destino').html(opciones);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-destino"><option>Seleccione una...</option></select>
<button type="button">Agregar opciones!</button>
```